# Update table error in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I'm working on an website and made an form where you can add vehicles. Now I created a form where you should be able to edit them, but when I press on edit vehicle it gives out my default error message

> Beim Speichern ist leider ein Fehler aufgetreten

Now I need your help. I have no clue where the problem could be, but I think it has to do something with the update query

```
 $showFormular = true; //Variable ob das Registrierungsformular anezeigt werden soll
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=', '', '');

    if(isset($_GET['bearbeiten'])) {
        $error = false;
        $EKNR = $_POST['EKNR'];
        $EKDatum = $_POST['EK-Datum'];
        $RGNummer = $_POST['RG-Nummer'];
        $Marke = $_POST['Marke'];
        $Modell = $_POST['Modell'];
        $EZ = $_POST['EZ'];
        $MotorNummer = $_POST['Motornummer'];
        $Fin = $_POST['FIN'];
        $KM = $_POST['KM'];
        $VK = $_POST['VK'];
        $EKBrutto = $_POST['EK-Brutto'];
        $EKNetto = $_POST['EK-Netto'];
        $VKDatum = $_POST['Verkaufsdatum'];
        $Lack = $_POST['Farbe'];

        //Keine Fehler, wir können den Nutzer registrieren
        if(!$error) {   
            $statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `Fahrzeugverkauf` SET `EKNR`=[$EKNR],`EKDatum`=[$EKDatum],`RGNummer`=[$RGNummer],`Marke`=[$Marke],`Modell`=[$Modell],`EZ`=[$EZ],`MotorNr`=[$MotorNummer],`FIN`=[$Fin],`KM`=[$KM],`VK`=[$VK],`EKBrutto`=[$EKBrutto],`EKNetto`=[$EKNetto],`Farbe`=[$Lack],`VKDatum`=[$VKDatum] WHERE EKNR = $id");
                $result = $statement->execute(array('EKNR' => '$EKNR', 'EKDatum' => '$EKDatum', 'RGNummer' => '$RGNummer', 'Marke' => '$Marke', 'Modell' => '$Modell', 'EZ' => '$EZ', 'MotorNr' => '$MotorNummer', 'FIN' => '$Fin', 'KM' => '$KM', 'VK' => '$VK', 'EKBrutto' => '$EKBrutto', 'EKNetto' => '$EKNetto', 'Farbe' => '$Lack', 'VKDatum' => '$VKDatum'));

                if($result) {       
                echo 'Das Fahrzeug wurde erfolgreich hinzugefügt.';

                $showFormular = false;
            } else {
                echo 'Beim Abspeichern ist leider ein Fehler aufgetreten<br>'
;
```

Comment: Bitte beantworte deine Frage in einer Antwort, und markiere diese Antwort dann als akzeptiert. Bitte editiere die Antwort nicht in die Frage hinein!

Comment: Pro-tips for getting the best results out of Stack Overflow: (a) avoid obviously offensive messages in your avatars; (b) if someone puts a lot of effort into assisting you, do not make a code change (e.g. PDO to mysqli) that invalidates all their effort; (c) if someone assists you, be more detailed than "still wont work", otherwise it is hard to know how to help you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved code:

```
<?php
function updater($value,$value2,$value3,$value4,$value5,$value6,$value7,$value8,$value9,$value10,$value11,$value12,$value13,$value14,$value15,$value16,$value17,$value18){
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli( 'localhost' , 'user' , 'pass' ,'db_name' );
    $value =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value);
    $value2 =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value2);
    $value3 =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value3);
    $value4 =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value4);
    $value5 =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value5);
    $value6 =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value6);
    $value7 =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value7);
    $value8 =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value8);
    $value9 =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value9);
    $value10 =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value10);
    $value11 =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value11);
    $value12 =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value12);
    $value13 =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value13);
    $value14 =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value14);
    $value15 =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value15);
    $value16 =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value16);
    $value17 =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value17);
    $value18 =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value18);
    // Check connection

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }   
    $sql = "UPDATE Fahrzeugverkauf SET EKNR='{$value}', EKDatum='{$value3}' , RGNummer='{$value4}' , Marke='{$value5}' , Modell='{$value6}' , Farbe='{$value7}', VKNummer='{$value8}', EZ='{$value9}', FIN='{$value10}', KM='{$value11}', VK='{$value12}', EKBrutto='{$value13}', EKNetto='{$value14}', VKDatum='{$value15}', MotorNr='{$value16}', Status='{$value17}', Anmerkung='{$value18}' WHERE EKNR='{$value2}'";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
}   

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $value = $_POST['EKNR'];
    $value2 = $_POST['EKNR2'];
    $value3 = $_POST['EK-Datum'];
    $value4 = $_POST['RG-Nummer'];
    $value5 = $_POST['Marke'];
    $value6 = $_POST['Modell'];
    $value7 = $_POST['Farbe'];
    $value8 = $_POST['VKnummer'];
    $value9 = $_POST['EZ'];
    $value10 = $_POST['FIN'];
    $value11 = $_POST['KM'];
    $value12 = $_POST['VK'];
    $value13 = $_POST['EK-Brutto'];
    $value14 = $_POST['EK-Netto'];
    $value15 = $_POST['Verkaufsdatum'];
    $value16 = $_POST['Motornummer'];
    $value17 = $_POST['selektion'];
    $value18 = $_POST['anmerkung'];
    updater($value,$value2,$value3,$value4,$value5,$value6,$value7,$value8,$value9,$value10,$value11,$value12,$value13,$value14,$value15,$value16,$value17,$value18);
}
?>
```

Comment: It is generally considered safer to use parameter binding instead of escaping these days, since there are some edge-case injection attacks involving extended character sets. The good news is that MySQLi supports parameter binding directly.

Answer (score 1):

Prepared statements have different SQL syntax for parameters. Instead of `[$EKNR]` use `:EKNR`.

And then when you are executing it pass the parameters in an array: `array(':EKNR' => $EKNR,...`.

> The SQL statement can contain zero or more named (:name) or question
>   mark (?) parameter markers for which real values will be substituted
>   when the statement is executed.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

#### Update

You have several errors in your code:

1. Remove quotes around the values you pass. This: `'$Modell'` will save the literal value "$Model1" and not the value, stored in `$Modell` variable.
2. Parameter names must match the names in SQL. For example, in SQL you have:

   ```
   `MotorNr` = :MotorNummer,
   ```

   But you pass a parameter:

   ```
   ':MotorNr' => $MotorNummer,
   ```

   `:MotorNr` must be replaced with `:MotorNummer`. There are several mistakes like this. Fix them all.
3. Your code is [vulnerable to SQL injection.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) At the end you pass a variable directly into SQL without using parameters:

   ```
   EKNR = $id
   ```

   Replace this with:

   ```
   EKNR = :id
   ```

   And pass an extra parameter into execute:

   ```
   ':id' => $id
   ```
4. No need  to save the id value:

   ```
   SET `EKNR`=:EKNR
   ```

   As far as I understand `EKNR` is the id of the record. No need to save it, it will stay the same.

Comment: I tried it like you wrote , but it's outputting another error now : Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in /volume1/web/34/fahrzeuge_bearbeiten.php on line 134 Beim Abspeichern ist leider ein Fehler aufgetreten

Comment: @MaxBogatec Please, update your question and show us the code that you've written. No need for the form code.

Comment: Updated , still no clue what's wrong ....

Comment: @MaxBogatec Answer updated.

Comment: Updated, MotorNr is the db value and $MotorNummer selects it from the form...

Comment: @MaxBogatec You need to run $statement = $pdo->prepare("SQL here").

Comment: Solved it , i used mysqli instead

Comment: @MaxBogatec You had to make just 1 step to make it work in PDO. Put your mysqli code as an answer and accept it please. So the question could be closed.

Comment: @halfer Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the array you are passing to execute remove the single quotes around the values in the array.

```
$result = $statement->execute(array(
    ':EKNR'     => $EKNR        ,
    ':EKDatum'  => $EKDatum     ,
    ':RGNummer' => $RGNummer    ,
    ':Marke'    => $Marke       ,
    ':Modell'   => $Modell      ,
    ':EZ'       => $EZ          ,
    ':MotorNr'  => $MotorNummer ,
    ':FIN'      => $Fin         ,
    ':KM'       => $KM          ,
    ':VK'       => $VK          ,
    ':EKBrutto' => $EKBrutto    ,
    ':EKNetto'  => $EKNetto     ,
    ':Farbe'    => $Lack        ,
    ':VKDatum'  => $VKDatum     ,
));
```

Comment: updated, still wont work!

Comment: You have 2 variable name mismatches between your retrieval of POST values and what you are using in the query. You use ':FIN' in the execute but :Fin in the query so those do not match. You also use :Farbe in the execute but :Lack in the query and those do not match either. Correct both of those names and see if things work.